# Как сделать, что бы блок вылезал слева/справа при скролле?

Tags: jquery, css

Вообщем, такая задача:

Когда блок с информацией появляется в видимости, он должен вылезать слева или справа
Пробовал такое делать с Animate.css и WOW.js, но хочу сделать теперь с css+jQuery

Спасибо

Comment: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Comment: как ему вылазить если он итак в области видимости?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так это сделать:

```
$(window).scroll( function(){

    $('.fbox').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

           $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},2000);

        }

    }); 

});
```

Где в if прописываем, что именно нам нужно выполнять.
[Ссылка на codepen.](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/dqmxy)

Comment: Спасибо большущее